# .net core multiple forms on one page validation

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

i need to make .net core page that has two forms. i've made everything work, but now i am struggling with asp-validation-summary, since i have two same elements on page, whenever i have error with form validation (serverside) it prints out errors on both places...

how can i differentiate these errors regarding form that i clicked?

```
 <form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login" asp-route-returnurl="@ViewData["ReturnUrl"]" id="loginForm" class="sky-form" method="post">

LOGIN INPUTS

<div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>

</form>

<form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Register" asp-route-returnurl="@ViewData["ReturnUrl"]" id="registerForm" class="sky-form" method="post">

REGISTER INPUTS

 <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>

 </form>
```

Comment: What does the controller code look like?  Roughly?  Is the same handler handling both Account/Login and Account/Register?

Comment: Hi... i forgot to say:
i have used jquery.validate and inside that code it makes sure that it goes to seperate actions in the same controller

Comment: I have the exact same problem, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

i didn't find proper solution but there is a workaround with ViewData in controller methods:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ViewData["requestForm"] = "login";
```

and

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ViewData["requestForm"] = "register";
```

and then modify login form:

```
            <form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login" asp-route-returnurl="@ViewData["ReturnUrl"]" id="loginForm" class="sky-form" method="post"> 
                @if(((string)ViewData["requestForm"])=="login")
                {
                    <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger "></div>
                }

            </form>
```

and register form:

```
            <form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Register" asp-route-returnurl="@ViewData["ReturnUrl"]" id="registerForm" class="sky-form" method="post">
                @if(((string)ViewData["requestForm"])=="register")
                {
                    <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger "></div>
                }

            </form>
```